# Скачать файл по прямой ссылке с гугл диска без API

Tags: python

Много вариантов перепробовал.Но все дают один и тот же результат-- скачивается файл с набором символов[image: введите сюда описание изображения],а на самом деле там текстовик с фамилиями и суммами оплат.Что я имею ввиду под прямой ссылкой?если эту ссылку вставить в браузер то моментально начнется закачка

```
import urllib.request
url= 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1-1xvAlE9OZz83ZbfdJS9u_5WqWSm2ZahNW1'

destination = 'test'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, destination)
```

так тоже пробовал,результат тот же.набор символов

```
import wget
wget.download(url, destination)
```

Comment: у вас файл какого типа?

Comment: @Vitaliy Stop_RU_war_in_UA  текстовик

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема, с которой вы столкнулись, заключается в том, что Google Drive обычно требует подтверждение на скачивание файлов, особенно если файлы считаются большими или подозрительными. Это подтверждение проявляется в виде страницы, которая говорит "Google Drive не может проверить этот файл на наличие вирусов" с кнопкой "Скачать все равно".

Чтобы обойти это, вы можете добавить дополнительный параметр confirm в URL. Однако значение этого параметра меняется и зависит от сессии, так что его нужно извлечь из страницы подтверждения.

Вот пример того, как это можно сделать с использованием библиотек requests и re:

```
import requests
import re

def download_google_drive_file(file_id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params={'id': file_id}, stream=True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)

    if token:
        params = {'id': file_id, 'confirm': token}
        response = session.get(URL, params=params, stream=True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)

def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith('download_warning'):
            return value
    return None

def save_response_content(response, destination):
    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(32768):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

file_id = "1-1xvAlE9OZz83ZbfdJS9u_5WqWSm2ZahNW1"
destination = "test.txt"
download_google_drive_file(file_id, destination)
```

Comment: файл не большой.500 килобайт.Никакого подтверждения не требует гугл драйв.есть прямая ссылка на файл.  Причем проверка если файл скачивается?Другое дело что он скачивается в какой то непонятной кодировке.Скрин с скачиваемой информацией приложил в посте
@Vitaliy Stop_RU_war_in_UA